# Ramda ifElse behaving strangely

Tags: javascript, ramda.js

Why when I run the `ifElse` method here does `false` log "function two (onTruthy)"?

```
var x = R.ifElse(R.T, function(){
  console.log("function two (onTruthy)")
  // console.log(arguments)
}, function(){
  console.log("function three (onFalsy)")
  // console.log(arguments)
})
x(false)
```

I'm thinking it's because R.T is always returning true. Perhaps using [_.isMatch](https://lodash.com/docs#isMatch) I can match it?

Update: Just tried:

```
var x = R.pipe(
  R.partialRight(R.match, true),
  R.partialRight(R.ifElse, function(){
    console.log("function two (onTruthy)")
    // console.log(arguments)
  }, function(){
    console.log("function three (onFalsy)")
    // console.log(arguments)
  })
)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`R.T`](http://ramdajs.com/docs/#T) evaluates `true` for any input. Thus `R.ifElse(R.T, f, g)` can be simplified to `f`.

It appears to me that you're looking for `R.ifElse(R.identity, f, g)`, but this could probably be better expressed via `... ? ... : ...`.